# Offset color and texture based on camera rotation

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, vector

I'm trying to mimic a particular material from Super Mario Galaxy, which seems to offset both its texture and colors in an odd way depending on the camera rotation.
See below gifs:[image]

[image]

So far, I have managed to emulate the color changing by way of vector transformation, but I'm stuck on how it seems to offset from the center of the object, and how the distortion pattern on the side also seems to change.[image]

How would I go about emulating this material more effectively with Blender nodes?